# Python flask url variable from another route as endpoint parameter

Tags: python, web, twitter, flask, tweepy

Hello guys i am new to flask and i have 1 question.
I have a route /tweeter where i show some data for the tweets which I take from twitter api with the help of tweepy.
How i can pass a variable from the /twitter route to create a new route with an atribute of the variable as endpoint.
for example:

```
@app.route('/twitter', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
  def twitter():
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = 'example', count=100, include_rts = True)
```

and in a new route i would like to pass tweets.text as endpoint parameter.

```
@app.route('/twitter/{twitter.text}')
  def newfunction(twitter.text):
.......
```

and some values from the tweets variable from above.

Comment: I'm not sure you really want to **create** a route. You can make *dynamic* routes with variable endpoints. Is that what you mean? What is the problem you're having?

Comment: Yes i would like when the user press on a tweet which is tweets.text from /twitter route to dynamic create a url /twitter/tweet's id or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define dynamic routes as follows:

```
@app.route('/twitter', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
  def twitter():
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = 'example', count=100, include_rts = True)

@app.route("/twitter/<tweet_text>")
def twitter_text(tweet_text):
    #dostuff
```

You can use `url_for` do generate the desired target

```
target_url = url_for('twitter_text', tweet_text="blah")
#'/twitter/blah'
```

Comment: If i have a variable in def twitter() for example a panda dataframe how i can pass and use it in the twitter_text function?

Comment: You can't pass arbitrary Python objects as endpoint parameters. Endpoint variables are always strings. Perhaps the question you've described is an xy problem. Take a look at [sessions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#sessions) and [g](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.g)

Comment: I dont want to pass object as an endpoint.I would like to pass it in the function and handle it as i did in the twitter() function

Comment: Then why is it necessary then to make it a route? Why not just make an ordinary function and call it directly from the `twitter()` route? What is the underlying reason for doing this?